# How to make an API request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to build an app that alerts when air quality rises above a certain level. I'm trying to get some json data from the api at https://api-docs.iqair.com, and they kindly provide simple copy and paste code. However, when I run this (with my API key), I get this error message:

> requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '{{urlExternalAPI}}v2/city?city=Los Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key={{my_key}}': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://{{urlExternalAPI}}v2/city?city=Los Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key={{my_key}}?`

I tried putting in the http, but then nothing happened.

Here's the code they provide:

```
import requests

url = "{{urlExternalAPI}}v2/city?city=Los Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key={{YOUR_API_KEY}}"

payload = {}
headers= {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Wait are you _literally_ sending over `"{{urlExternalAPI}}"` as a part of the URL instead of actually substituting it with the `"https://www.whatever.com/"` part of the URL? If so then that's obviously your issue.

Comment: @RandomDavis I know. I feel like a dope. But when I replace that with `https://www.iqair.com` I just get the HTML from that page. This is literally my first time doing this.

Comment: So if your URL is `https://www.example.com/` and your API key looks like `abcd1234`, you should be sending over `https://www.example.com/v2/city?city=Los Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key=abcd1234`. No curly braces at all. You're doing that, right? Removing the curly braces?

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes... I'm using `url = "https://www.iqair.com/air-pollution-data-api/?version=latest#275daeb0-d34d-408a-bc03-f74d097a4eae/v2/city?city=Los Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key=mykey"`

Comment: @RandomDavis I've tried just `https://www.iqair.com` but no matter what URL I put in there, it just returns HTML.

Comment: Okay so what happens when you paste that into a browser compared to when running it with Python? What do you expect to be returned instead of HTML?

Comment: I get a 404 page. I was expecting JSON data.

Comment: @RandomDavis never mind. I got it. the correct URL is `https://api.airvisual.com` to get the JSON data. That URL doesn't appear anywhere on the page. Very odd. I found it on some random blog post.

Comment: Hi, @ScottSmith! If your question is solved, you could close or answer it yourself. Maybe this will help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to put in the URL, and not use the curly brackets. Also, I couldn't find the correct URL, but after googling it, I found that I merely had to use the correct URL, which was `https://api.airvisual.com`.